# Routing TCP packets to a local UDP port

Tags: ssh, tcp, udp, netcat

A third party server sends UDP packets to an EC2 instance we've set up and I'm trying to route those packets to my local machine.

The client sends these packets to port 8975

To that effect I first established an ssh tunnel to my ec2 instance

```
ssh -4 -L 10000:localhost:10000 -i ~/.ssh/xxxx.pem ubuntu@13.xxx.x.xx
```

on my remote machine - I routed the packets received on port 8975 to 10000
using this command

```
netcat -l -u -p 8975 > /tmp/udp2tcp | netcat -l -p 10000 < /tmp/udp2tcp
```

`udp2tcp` is a fifo file

on my local machine - I'm taking the `tcp` packets I receive and converting them back to UDP

```
netcat localhost 10000 > /tmp/tcp2udp | netcat -l -u -p 8975 < /tmp/tcp2udp
```

When i run `netcat localhost 10000` - i can see the packets flowing in on my local machine

but for some reason , there is no packets being routed as udp to port 8975 - i'm not sure what exactly i need to do

when i run `sudo tcpdump -i any -S -vvv port 10000`

This shows me packets flogin in

```
15:39:10.053013 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 64725, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.48974 > localhost.webmin: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x5674), ack 1261213200, win 10567, options [nop,nop,TS val 1064223053 ecr 1064223053], length 0
```

but when i run sudo `tcpdump -i any -S -v port 8975` - i dont see anything

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to SSH port forwarding, you may forward those UDP packets to your local machine by using point-to-point tunnel devices, SSH and the procedure explained below.

In the EC2 instance, do the following:

1. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, set configuration parameter `PermitTunnel` to either `point-to-point` or `yes`.
2. Create a point-to-point tunnel device that will receive UDP packets from the public network:

   ```
   $ sudo ip tuntap add dev tun8975 mode tun user ubuntu
   $ sudo ip addr add dev tun8975 172.16.19.22 peer 172.16.19.21
   $ sudo ip link set dev tun8975 up
   ```
3. Configure either IPTABLES or NFTABLES to forward such UDP packets to the tunnel device

   ```
   $ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING '!' -i tun8975 -p udp --dport 8975 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.19.21:8975
   ```

   ```
   $ sudo nft add rule ip nat PREROUTING iifname '!=' "tun8975" udp dport 8975 dnat to 172.16.19.21:8975
   ```
4. Ensure that kernel allows IP packet forwarding among network interfaces:

   ```
   $ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
   ```

Afterwards, in your local machine, do the following:

1. Create a point-to-point tunnel device that SSH will use to output forwarded UDP packets:

   ```
   $ sudo ip tuntap add dev tun8975 mode tun
   $ sudo ip addr add dev tun8975 172.16.19.21 peer 172.16.19.22
   $ sudo ip link set dev tun8975 up
   ```
2. Request SSH to forward traffic between the tunnel devices through its secure channel:

   ```
   $ sudo ssh -4 -o Tunnel=point-to-point -w 8975:8975 -i ~/.ssh/xxxx.pem ubuntu@13.xxx.x.xx
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues in your approach to solve the communication problem.

The first issue is in the command run in the local machine. I believe that the `-l` flag on the UDP part of the `netcat` command pipeline should be removed and another process in your local machine (which could be another `netcat`) should listen to UDP port 8975 and receive datagrams sent to that port. `netcat` in this scenario would run in client mode and generate such datagrams.

The second issue is on the way these command lines are constructed:

- On the remote machine

  ```
  $ netcat -l -u -p 8975 > /tmp/udp2tcp | netcat -l -p 10000 < /tmp/udp2tcp
  ```
- On the local machine

  ```
  $ netcat localhost 10000 > /tmp/tcp2udp | netcat -l -u -p 8975 < /tmp/tcp2udp
  ```

They mix redirections and pipelines. Although I did read *Pipelines* and *Redirection* sections from [Bash manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) and figured out that pipelines would be processed before redirects, I am unable to understand how the shell would connect standard streams using such syntax.

`netcat` works by forwarding data from its standard input to the sending side of the socket and forwarding data from the receiving side of the socket to its standard output. It does so regardless of whether such socket is a client socket connecting to a remote server or a server socket accepting a connection from a remote client. Because of that, in order to forwarding data between a TCP and a UDP socket, you will need to connect standard streams appropriately, that is, you will need to connect STDOUT of the TCP `netcat` to STDIN of the UDP `netcat` and STDOUT of the UDP `netcat` to STDIN of the TCP `netcat` at the same time.

Perhaps the command lines you are running already achieve that objective. Despite of that, I propose a more explicit data forwarding, by using these commands:

- On the remote machine

  ```
  $ cat /tmp/udp2tcp | netcat -l -u -p 8975 | netcat -l -p 10000 > /tmp/udp2tcp
  ```
- On the local machine

  ```
  $ cat /tmp/tcp2udp | netcat localhost 10000 | netcat -u localhost 8975 > /tmp/tcp2udp
  ```

In both cases, an anonymous pipe would connect first `netcat`'s STDOUT to second `netcat`'s STDIN and a named pipe (fifo) would connect second `netcat`'s STDOUT back to first `netcat`'s STDIN.

Consider instructing `netcat` to use only IPv4 stack by adding the `-4` flag to command line arguments. This might help if the process listening to UDP port 8975 is not compatible with IPv6.